# Code won't output the right String

Tags: java

The Error is that: String which doesn't == withdraw, whatever i put, it will just say, deposit.
i want to be able to use both (withdraw) & (Deposit).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BasicClasses {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to First National Bank (FNB)");
        Scanner Key = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Question = Key.nextLine();
        BasicClasses flix = new BasicClasses();

        System.out.print(" | Withdraw | or | Deposit | [ ");
        Scanner Key1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Which = Key.nextLine();

        if(Which == "withdraw") {
            System.out.println("|Withdraw| - | How much do you Want to Withdraw?");

        } else {
            System.out.println("|Deposit| - | How much will you be Depositing?");
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

compare like this :
`if(Which.equals("withdraw"))`

Comment: Thnx :), worked perfect.